# How can I get the next $.each iteration for comparison purposes when using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the next iteration of a selected element so I can compare values between them, I have the following code

```
$('#routemap tbody tr').each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(3) input').val()) == 0){
        $(this).next().find('td:eq(2)').val($(this).find('td:eq(2)').val());
        return;
    }
});
```

As you can see I am checking the current selection for a zero value and then changing the next items value to match the current one.

Only problem is I am not getting the value back for the next selected element

I am attaching the originating table for this query

```
<table id="routemap" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Order</th>
 <th>Requested Time</th>
 <th>Planned Time</th>
 <th title="Driving Distance To The Next Point">Driving(km)</th>
 <th title="Travelling Time Between Points">Driving Time</th>
 <th title="Turn Around Time At Site Plus Driving Time To Next point">TAT+Driving</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr id="3">
 <td>3</td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" value="2014-08-10 12:00:00" style="border:none;" readonly="readonly" size="17">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input class="date" type="text" value="2014-08-10 12:00:00" size="17">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input id="dist_3" type="text" size="5">
  </td>
<td>
 H:
 <input id="dth_3" type="text" value="0" size="3">
  M:
<input id="dtm_3" type="text" value="0" size="3">
</td>
<td>
H:
<input id="tath_3" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 M:
<input id="tatm_3" type="text" value="0" size="3">
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="6">
<td>6</td>
<td>
<input type="text" value="2014-08-10 11:00:00" style="border:none;" readonly="readonly" size="17">
</td>
<td>
<input class="date" type="text" value="2014-08-10 11:00:00" size="17">
</td>
<td>
 <input id="dist_6" type="text" size="5">
 </td>
 <td>
 H:
 <input id="dth_6" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 M:
 <input id="dtm_6" type="text" value="0" size="3">
</td> 
<td>
H:
<input id="tath_6" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 M:
 <input id="tatm_6" type="text" value="0" size="3">
</td>
 </tr>
<tr id="2">
<td>2</td>
<td>
<input type="text" value="2014-08-10 11:00:00" style="border:none;" readonly="readonly" size="17">
</td>
<td>
<input class="date" type="text" value="2014-08-10 11:00:00" size="17">
</td>
<td>
 <input id="dist_2" type="text" size="5">
</td>
<td>
H:
<input id="dth_2" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 M:
<input id="dtm_2" type="text" value="0" size="3">
</td>
<td> 
H:
<input id="tath_2" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 M:
<input id="tatm_2" type="text" value="0" size="3">
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="5">
<td>5</td>
<td>
<input type="text" value="2014-08-10 07:00:00" style="border:none;" readonly="readonly" size="17">
</td>
<td>
<input class="date" type="text" value="2014-08-10 07:00:00" size="17">
</td>
<td>
<input id="dist_5" type="text" size="5">
</td>
<td>  
H:
<input id="dth_5" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 M:
<input id="dtm_5" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 </td>
<td>
H:
<input id="tath_5" type="text" value="0" size="3">
 M:
<input id="tatm_5" type="text" value="0" size="3">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the soultion that works using the index as suggested

```
$('#routemap tbody tr').each(function(index,value){  
    if(parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(3) input').val()) == 0){
        $(this).next().find('td:eq(2) input').val($(this).find('td:eq(2) input').val());
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: you will get the index as the first param in the each loop, you can use it + 1

Comment: can also use `$(this).next()` to get next sibling

Comment: I don't think we can't help you without seeing the corresponding `HTML` structure.